# Нововведення, новація чи новела?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, вибір-слова, росіянізм

В одній із недавніх [публікацій VoxUkraine](https://voxukraine.org/2017/08/02/shho-ne-tak-z-oplatoyu-pratsi-derzhavnih-sluzhbovtsiv-ta-yak-tse-zminiti/), пишучи про зміни у законодавстві, вжили слово ***новела*** в наступному контексті:

> Закон ввів дві важливі *новели*. Перша з них – відкриті конкурси ...

Позаяк, згідно із СУМ-11, *[новела](http://sum.in.ua/s/novela)* — це вид художнього твору і не синонім слів *[новація](http://sum.in.ua/s/novacija)* та *[нововведення](http://sum.in.ua/s/novovvedennja)*.

Але словник застарілий, а мова розвивається щодня. Чи є припустимим наразі вживання слова *новела* для позначення оновлень/нових змін?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В юриспруденції термін ***новела*** вживається в такому значенні:

> **[Новела](http://search.ligazakon.ua/l_doc2.nsf/link1/TS002314.html)** (від лат. novellae leges - нові закони)
>
> у праві - історико-правовий термін, що позначає сукупність законів,
>   виданих після закінчення кодифікації, які доповнюють або змінюють
>   будь-які з встановлених нею норм права. З'явилися під час перших
>   кодифікацій римського права. Умовно термін "новела" в теорії права
>   застосовується й для позначення нововведень у попереднє законодавство
>   (напр., для нових положень у тому чи ін. кодексі порівняно з
>   попередніми).
>
> (З практики застосування термінів, слів та словосполучень у
>   юриспруденції)

Це [усталений і широковживаний термін](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=AciCWfH7ItHi8Afw3IeIDw) в означеному контексті.